# Member variable seemingly gets initialized twice

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I have the following classes:

Bar.hpp

```cpp
#include <string>

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(const std::string& info);
    std::string getInfo() { return info; }

    protected:
    
    private:
        std::string info;

};
```

Bar.cpp:

```cpp
#include <Bar.hpp>

Bar::Bar(const std::string& info)
        : info(info) { }
```

Foo.hpp:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <Bar.hpp>

class Foo
{
    public:
        static void printInfoStore();
        static Foo* getFoo(const std::string& name);

        Foo() {};

        std::string getName() { return name; }
        std::vector<Bar> getBars();
        void addBar(const std::string& info);

    protected:

    private:
        static std::vector<Foo> infoStore;
        Foo(const std::string& name);
        std::vector<Bar> bars{};
        std::string name;

};
```

Foo.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <Foo.hpp>

Foo::Foo(const std::string& name)
        : name(name) { }


//static
std::vector<Foo> Foo::infoStore(0);

//static
void Foo::printInfoStore() {
    std::cout << "InfoStore is { ";
    for (Foo& foo : infoStore) {
        std::cout << foo.getName() << "=[ ";
        for (Bar& bar : foo.getBars()) {
            std::cout << bar.getInfo() << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "] ";
    }
    std::cout << " }" << std::endl;
}

//static
Foo* Foo::getFoo(const std::string& name) {
    for (Foo& foo : infoStore) {
        if (foo.getName() == name) {
            return &foo;
        }
    }
    Foo* foo = new Foo(name);
    infoStore.push_back(*foo);
    return foo;
}

std::vector<Bar> Foo::getBars() {
    return bars;
}

void Foo::addBar(const std::string& info) {
    Bar* bar = new Bar(info);
    bars.push_back(*bar);
}
```

Basically there is a static vector that holds multiple Foo objects each of which has a vector of Bar objects.

Then I have the following main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <Foo.hpp>
#include <Bar.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo::printInfoStore();

    Foo::getFoo("Foo1")->addBar("info11");  // info11 is not added to Foo1
    Foo::printInfoStore();

    Foo::getFoo("Foo1")->addBar("info12");
    Foo::printInfoStore();

    Foo::getFoo("Foo1")->addBar("info13");
    Foo::printInfoStore();

    Foo::getFoo("Foo2")->addBar("info21");  // info21 is not added to Foo2
    Foo::printInfoStore();

    Foo::getFoo("Foo2")->addBar("info22");
    Foo::printInfoStore();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is the following:

```
InfoStore is {  }
InfoStore is { Foo1=[ ]  }
InfoStore is { Foo1=[ info12 ]  }
InfoStore is { Foo1=[ info12 info13 ]  }
InfoStore is { Foo1=[ info12 info13 ] Foo2=[ ]  }
InfoStore is { Foo1=[ info12 info13 ] Foo2=[ info22 ]  }
```

The strange thing is that the first `Bar`s added for each Foo object (`info11` and `info21`) do not get added. My guess is that there might be a second initialization of the `bars` vector that happens after the parent Foo object but I don't know if this is the case, nor I can find a rationale behind it.

I tried to initialize the bars vector explicitly within the foo constructor but to no avail: the first Bar added is always discarded.

So why does it happen? What's wrong with my code? What can be done to avoid that behavior?

Comment: Your getters return copy and not /*const*/ reference.

Comment: All your `new` seems suspicious.

Comment: `Foo* foo = new Foo(name); infoStore.push_back(*foo); return foo;` --> Are you using Java as a model in writing C++ code?  As mentioned, those functions should return a reference, thus making the code simpler and without memory leaks., For example: `infoStore.push_back({name}); return infoStore.back();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your `new`s are causing memory leaks. None of this code should be using `new` at all, since none of the `vector`s are holding pointers.

For that matter, since `getFoo()` always returns a valid object, whether an existing object or newly-pushed object, it *should* return a `Foo&` reference to that object rather than a `Foo*` pointer (you *can* return a pointer if you really want to, but I would not advise it).

Either way, you would have to make sure that whatever you do return actually refers to an object that is inside of your `vector`. Your output is not what you expect because the code is NOT doing this correctly, which is the root of your problem.

When you call `getFoo()` for a *non-existent* object, you create a `new` object, then push a *copy* of that object into your `vector`, and then return a pointer to the `new`'ed object, not a pointer to the *copied* object.  So, any values you subsequently store in the `new`'ed object appear to be discarded when you print the `vector` later, since the values don't exist in the *copied* object that is actually inside of the `vector`.  When you call `getFoo()` again for an *existing* object, you return a pointer to the *copied* object that is inside the `vector`, and you do not create a `new` object.

On a similar note, `getBars()` should also return a *reference* to its `vector`, not return a *copy* of its `vector` by value.

With all of that said, try something more like this instead:

Bar.hpp

```cpp
#include <string>

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(const std::string& info);
    std::string getInfo() const;

private:
    std::string info;
};
```

Bar.cpp:

```cpp
#include <Bar.hpp>

Bar::Bar(const std::string& info)
    : info(info) { }

std::string Bar::getInfo() const
    { return info; }
```

Foo.hpp:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <Bar.hpp>

class Foo
{
public:
    static void printInfoStore();
    static Foo& getFoo(const std::string& name);

    std::string getName() const;

    std::vector<Bar>& getBars();
    const std::vector<Bar>& getBars() const;

    void addBar(const std::string& info);

private:
    static std::vector<Foo> infoStore;
    std::vector<Bar> bars;
    std::string name;

    Foo(const std::string& name);
};
```

Foo.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <Foo.hpp>

Foo::Foo(const std::string& name)
    : name(name) { }

//static
std::vector<Foo> Foo::infoStore;

//static
void Foo::printInfoStore() {
    std::cout << "InfoStore is { ";
    for (const Foo& foo : infoStore) {
        std::cout << foo.getName() << "=[ ";
        for (const Bar& bar : foo.getBars()) {
            std::cout << bar.getInfo() << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "] ";
    }
    std::cout << " }" << std::endl;
}

//static
Foo& Foo::getFoo(const std::string& name) {
    for (Foo& foo : infoStore) {
        if (foo.getName() == name) {
            return foo;
        }
    }
    infoStore.push_back(Foo(name));
    return infoStore.back();

    // or, in C++11..14:
    // infoStore.emplace_back(name);
    // return infoStore.back();

    // or, in C++17 onward:
    // return infoStore.emplace_back(name);
}

std::string Foo::getName() const {
    return name;
}

std::vector<Bar>& Foo::getBars() {
    return bars;
}

const std::vector<Bar>& Foo::getBars() const {
    return bars;
}

void Foo::addBar(const std::string& info) {
    bars.push_back(Bar(info));

    // or, in C++11 onward:
    // bars.emplace_back(info);
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <Foo.hpp>
#include <Bar.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo::printInfoStore();

    Foo::getFoo("Foo1").addBar("info11");
    Foo::printInfoStore();

    Foo::getFoo("Foo1").addBar("info12");
    Foo::printInfoStore();

    Foo::getFoo("Foo1").addBar("info13");
    Foo::printInfoStore();

    Foo::getFoo("Foo2").addBar("info21");
    Foo::printInfoStore();

    Foo::getFoo("Foo2").addBar("info22");
    Foo::printInfoStore();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You store copy in your vector (with memory leaks).

Fixed version:

```
Foo* Foo::getFoo(const std::string& name) {
    for (Foo& foo : infoStore) {
        if (foo.getName() == name) {
            return &foo;
        }
    }
    return &infoStore.emplace_back(Foo{name});
}

void Foo::addBar(const std::string& info) {
    bars.emplace_back(info);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/baxWoKss4)

Comment: Note that `emplace_back()` did not return a reference until C++17, so if you are using C++11 or C++14 then you will have to use `infoStore.emplace_back(Foo{name}); return &infoStore.back();` instead.

Comment: Thank you Jarod for finding the problem. +1 for the demo.